# Create on the fly web service, Dynamic web service invoker

Tags: java, web-services, dynamic, wsdl

I need to create dynamic invoker of webservices based on their WSDL.
any idea?
thanks

Comment: did you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 2):

See [JAX-RPC](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/WebServices/WSPack2/jaxrpc.html); what you need is Dynamic proxies or Dynamic Invocation Interface (DII) if client doesn't know the remote method name or its signature.

[Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipjaxrpc/) a good example of what you can do with JAX-RPC having just a WSDL as input.

As said in the comment, JAX-RPC is evolved to [JAX-WS](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/).

Comment: no - JAX-RPC is outdated. JAX-WS is "fresh"

Comment: Does it mean that anyway I should parse the wsdl to get the required information like: servicename, portTypes, operations,...?

Comment: @Bozho Ok for the freshness :); but help me to find an example with JAX-WS that uses DII.

Comment: JAX-WS's DII is the Dispatch object (`javax.xml.ws.Dispatch`).

Answer (score 2):

have you read this pages ?

> [Dynamic Discovery and Invocation of Web services](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-udax.html)
>
> [Dynamically Invoking a Web Service](http://blogs.msdn.com/kaevans/archive/2006/04/27/dynamically-invoking-a-web-service.aspx)

Update

[C# – Dynamically Invoke Web Service At Runtime](http://www.crowsprogramming.com/archives/66)

[Creating a dynamic Web service to simplify code From 2006](http://www.builderau.com.au/program/web/soa/Applied-Reflection-Creating-a-dynamic-Web-service-to-simplify-code/0,339024632,339271837,00.htm)

Comment: "Dynamic Discovery and Invocation of Web services", Date:  01 Aug 2001.
Isnt little bit complicated, doesnt exist easier way?

Comment: Actualy I need to write the invoker in Java, Eclipse + JSF.

Comment: First link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/dynamic-clients.html

Generates clients on the fly.

Comment: yes, but anyway before I invoke the webservice I should know the operation and the message?

Comment: Ok, If you dont know what operation/message you are calling, how are you plannign to invoke a webservice? This CXF thingy generates clients on the fly in that if the wsdl grammar has changed it gets regenerated. You still need to know an operation name :)

Comment: You are right :) I need to know the operation name:) But what about the messages sent and recieved? If I should make dynamic client invoker, it means that I should write wsdl parser anyway?