# How to parse WSDL in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I need parser for WSDL to get the messages, portTypes, operations, bindings, services,...
I hope some parser already exists. So, any guidlines?

Answer (score 3):

Hope this link will be useful for you to choose a WSDL parser, [`Parse WSDL Effectively`](http://oracled.wordpress.com/2009/02/04/parse-wsdl-effectively/) (look at the archive of this Link: [`Web Archive`](http://web.archive.org/web/20121008085122/http://oracled.wordpress.com/2009/02/04/parse-wsdl-effectively)).

I have tried using [`Apache Woden`](http://ws.apache.org/woden/), [`WSDL4J`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl4j/) and [`Membrane SOA`](http://www.membrane-soa.org/). Apache Woden or Membrane SOA would do fine.

Comment: The "Parse WSDL Effectively" link is now dead. Apache Woden only supports WSDL 2.0, not WSDL 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Several Web Service stacks are available.

Have a look at the Metro stack.  Open Source and available directly in Java 6.

Comment: I have to make dynamic service invoker based on the WSDL. Some direction how to do it with Metro?

Comment: Well I need to make dynamic form (service invoker), based on WSDL. Imagine that you recieve WSDL and you should generate form from it (input fields) and also possibility to invoke that operation. I have just repository of WSDLs. It should be enaugh dynamic that it can work for any WSDL. I hope I was clear enaugh.

Comment: Aren't you asking the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491598/create-on-the-fly-web-service-dynamic-web-service-invoker ?

Comment: I use the Web Service Explorer in Eclipse JEE to work with unknown WSDL's.   Is it an option just to use that?  "Any WSDL" would require quite a bit of hard work for you to implement.

Answer (score 0):

```
f wsdl = '''
<definitions name="AgencyManagementService"
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.org/NS1"
    xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.org/NS2">
    <ns1:message name="SomeRequest">
        <ns1:part name="parameters" element="SomeReq" />
    </ns1:message>
    <ns2:message name="SomeRequest">
        <ns2:part name="parameters" element="SomeReq" />
    </ns2:message>
</definitions>
'''

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(wsdl).declareNamespace(ns1: 'http://www.example.org/NS1', ns2: 'http://www.example.org/NS2')
println xml.'ns1:message'.'ns1:part'.size()
println xml.'ns2:message'.'ns2:part'.size()
```

Hope this helps. Groovy class can be called from any other Java class. Move all XML labor to Groovy :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `wsimport` tool documentation at  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html. It is a standard JDK tool that generates JAXB-based Java artifacts for interactions with web service.

Answer (score 0):

you can use membrane-soa for parsing wsdl files. add dependency from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.predic8/soa-model-core .

you can find documantation at http://membrane-soa.org/soa-model/ .

Answer (score -1):

use http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl4j/

```
public Definition readWSDLFile(String location) throws  WSDLException {
    WSDLReader reader = getWsdlFactoryInstance().newWSDLReader();
    reader.setFeature("javax.wsdl.importDocuments", true);
    return reader.readWSDL(location);
}
```