# Generate html form from wsdl

Tags: java, html, forms, wsdl

I need a way to generate HTML interface (form), starting from wsdl, to submit web service requests. The request submission is made by server side code. The user fills out the form and posts data.

I am looking for a library (Java) that might help me to write the code.

I'm not trying to create java classes of the web service, I have to generate form fields for any wsdl url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MikeC http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html is a tool to create HTML forms from WSDL documents. Unfortunately, its not a Java library and it also had at least one limitation: no multidimensional array support.

But with a little effort you should be able to write an own parser/transformer for your specific use case. See also [How to parse WSDL in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495740/how-to-parse-wsdl-in-java) to find more information about a WSDL parser for JAVA.

Also possible XSLT http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-xsltwsdl/.

Comment: Do you mean you want to build something like a simple soapUI? i.e. A user loads a WSDL and a web page is displayed to take as input the various elements of the request message. The user fills in the values and clicks a button to submit the request to the service and the response elements are displayed in the web page. Is that what you want to build? A bit like http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html