# Dynamically Invoking a Web Service

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services

I want to dynamically invoke web services using VB .Net. 
I can use the web service when adding it as a web reference in Visual Studio, so the web service side is fine.

I was following this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2006/04/27/dynamically-invoking-a-web-service.aspx) which was kind of successful, that is, it works for some but not all services I tried. If it fails, it throws:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to Import Binding from Namespace
...
Unabled to find 'http://service/:helloWorld'
```

This lead me to this [Bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820122). I'm not quite sure if it is really related, because there are no `<inlcude>` elements in WSDL:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://service/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://service/" name="simple">
<types>
  <xsd:schema>
    <xsd:import namespace="http://service/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/simple/simple?xsd=1"/>
  </xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="helloWorld">
  <part name="parameters" element="tns:helloWorld"/>
</message>
<message name="helloWorldResponse">
  <part name="parameters" element="tns:helloWorldResponse"/>
</message>
<portType name="simple">
  <operation name="helloWorld">
    <input wsam:Action="http://service/simple/helloWorldRequest" message="tns:helloWorld"/>
    <output wsam:Action="http://service/simple/helloWorldResponse" message="tns:helloWorldResponse"/>
  </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="simplePortBinding" type="tns:simple">
  <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="helloWorld">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="simple">
    <port name="simplePort" binding="tns:simplePortBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/simple/simple"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

The imported xsd looks like this:

```
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://service/"><xs:element name="helloWorld" type="tns:helloWorld"/>
  <xs:element name="helloWorldResponse" type="tns:helloWorldResponse"/>
    <xs:complexType name="helloWorld">
      <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="helloWorldResponse">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="return" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
 </xs:schema>
```

Both are auto generated from a JAX-WS web service deployed on glassfish.

So the question is: What is causing this error and is there a workaround which does not involve changing the web service?

Comment: Related: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491598/create-on-the-fly-web-service-dynamic-web-service-invoker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491598/create-on-the-fly-web-service-dynamic-web-service-invoker)