# How to invoke webservice without creating any clients for it?

Tags: java, web-services

I was searching on google but not found any helpful article on this.
I want to invoke webservice methods.I have wdsl and i have to invoke dynamically without creating any stubs as such.Any example will be more helpful.

Comment: There is a way called REST its url based. I don't think you can invoke a WS without creating stubs if you have a ready made WSDL

Comment: i think there is a similar post on this topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491598/create-on-the-fly-web-service-dynamic-web-service-invoker

Comment: A webservice is nothing more then sending xml to an endpoint over some transport. Heck you could just create a `String` containting the XML and use a `HttpUrlConnection` (if the transport is HTTP) to send the XML to the endpoint. You can even use JAX-WS to dynamically (at runtime!) create a proxy for the webservice for you. No additional library needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soap Ui is a application used for testing the web service generated. You only need the Wsdl for doing the same.
[here](http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/getting-started.html) is a link.

1. right click the generated wsdl > run as > run in server.
2. copy the url from the address bar of the browser.
3. open soap iu and click on new project.
4. paste the url in the wsdl column.
5. the project will be listed with the name of the method.
6. expand the method and click on request1.
7. enter the values in the "?" which are the parameters to the method.
8. click the run button.

this a method for mocking the web service created without creating a client. The soap Ui application can work as client.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. After a little research i found this project on github which seems to fulfill your needs.

https://github.com/reficio/soap-ws

Here is some sample code from the github site which seems very easy and straightforward.

Consume a Web-Serivce in 60 seconds

Let's consume the CurrencyConverter Web-Service. Thanks to the fluent builders the API is straigtforward and intuitive. Does it need any explanation? Welcome to soap-ws :)

```
Wsdl wsdl = Wsdl.parse("http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL");

SoapBuilder builder = wsdl.binding()
    .localPart("CurrencyConvertorSoap")
    .find();
SoapOperation operation = builder.operation()
    .soapAction("http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate")
    .find();
Request request = builder.buildInputMessage(operation)

SoapClient client = SoapClient.builder()
    .endpointUrl("http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx")
    .build();
String response = client.post(request);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are searching for a tool for invoking web services. Better user [Soap UI](http://www.soapui.org/) 
Soap UI is a tool which acts as a client to connect with your webservices.

Answer (score 0):

You can this bellow class for invoke a soap webservices without creation any client.

```
public class SoapServiceCaller {

    public static String invokeSoapService(String endpointUrl, Map<String, String> headers, String body) throws IOException {

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(endpointUrl)).openConnection();

        // create body of request
        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] bodyBytes = body.getBytes();
        bout.write(bodyBytes);

        // Add Header into connection
        headers.put("Content-Length", String.valueOf(body.getBytes().length));
        headers.put("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        addHeaders(connection, headers);

        // Write the content of the request to the output stream of the HTTP Connection.
        OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
        out.write(bout.toByteArray());
        out.close();

        // Ready with sending the request.
        return getSendRequestAndGetResponse(connection);
    }

    private static void addHeaders(HttpURLConnection connection, Map<String, String> headers) {
        headers.forEach(connection::setRequestProperty);
    }

    private static String getSendRequestAndGetResponse(HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) builder.append(line);
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

and use bellow code to test it.

```
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    String body = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:web=\"http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/\"> <soap:Header/> <soap:Body> <web:NumberToDollars> <web:dNum>20</web:dNum> </web:NumberToDollars> </soap:Body> </soap:Envelope>";
    String endpointUrl = "https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso";
    String response = SoapServiceCaller.invokeSoapService(endpointUrl, headers, body);
    System.out.print(response);
```

I use this wsdl file for testing
https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/NumberConversion.wso?wsdl